# Please explain in simple terms why this code fragment has O(n^4) complexity?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Evaluate Big-Oh of the following code fragment:

```
sum = 0
for( i = 1; i < n; ++i )
    for( j = 1; j < i * i; ++j )
        if( j % i == 0 )
            for( k = 0; k < j; ++k )
                ++sum
```

This is a homework problem in a textbook for my algorithms class. The answer as stated in the textbook is `O(n^4)`. I've tried doing the problem many ways, but I am always getting `O(n^5)`.

I'm using the summation method and mathematically evaluating from the innermost nested loop outward. The summations are not shown here because I don't know how to express my math in this space, but please follow my work below.

Here is my logic for the innermost loop:

```
for( k = 0; k < j; ++k )
```

My thinking is that the inner loop makes `j+1` iterations, which can be as big as `i*i`, which itself can be as big as `n`, so this loop as an upper bound of `O(n^2)`.

Here is my logic for the middle loop:

```
for( j = 1; j < i * i; ++j )
```

`j` iterates as high as `i^2` times, which itself can go as high as `n`, so this loop has an upper bound of `O(n^2)`.

Here is my logic for the outer loop:

```
for( i = 1; i < n; ++i )
```

`i` iterates as high as `n` times, so the loop has an upper-bound of `O(n)`.

```
O(n * n^2 * n^2) = O(n^5)
```

Again, the answer is `O(n^4)`. Please help me, using mathematical loops to aid your answer. Please use simple language. I am still new to algorithm analysis.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate of another post. I just don't understand the explanation people gave for that post..

Comment: When you claim to be aware of essentially the same question, please provide a link - and a description which part of the answer(s) you don't follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is in this line:

```
if( j % i == 0 )
```

What this does is ensures the inner loop only executes when `j` is an exact multiple of `i`; otherwise no work is done.

So one shortcut you could think about is saying that this is `O(n * n^2 / n * n^2) = O(n^4)`.

Another way you could think about it is that this is equivalent to writing:

```
sum = 0
for( i = 1; i < n; ++i )
    for( j = 1; j < i * i; j += i )
        for( k = 0; k < j; ++k )
            ++sum
```

which is `O(N^4)` by inspection.

Comment: Could you explain how you simplified the code fragment? I am especially confused how you got j += i in the middle loop

Comment: @lasko: Try a few values of `n` and follow the values of `j` and `k` (in your mind or using pencil&paper of your favourite visualisation/debugging tool - whatever).